# Blender Quits while trying to render in Command Line

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, error, command-line

I Am getting an Error when i'm trying to render in CMDLine `2023-12-18 21:12:13,417 - app - WARNING - REGISTRATION FAILED: MODULE NOT FOUND (ui_registration.py:57)` i diddnt find anything on the net so i am asking know here does anyone know how to fix this?
This is the rest of the console Output:

```
Add-on not loaded: 'MapsModelsImporter' cause: No module named 'MapsModelsImporter'
hello
Add-on not loaded: 'BSA_Layout' cause: No module named 'BSA_Layout'
2023-12-18 21:12:13,414 - app - DEBUG - REGISTERING BLENDARMOCAP (ui_registration.py:40)
2023-12-18 21:12:13,414 - app - DEBUG - <class '_blender.interface.ui_preferences.PREFERENCES_OT_install_dependencies_button'> (ui_registration.py:43)
2023-12-18 21:12:13,414 - app - DEBUG - <class '_blender.interface.ui_preferences.BLENDARMOCAP_preferences'> (ui_registration.py:43)
2023-12-18 21:12:13,414 - app - DEBUG - <class '_blender.interface.ui_panels.UI_PT_warning_panel'> (ui_registration.py:43)
2023-12-18 21:12:13,416 - app - DEBUG - TRY ACCESS INSTALLED DEPENDENCIES (ui_registration.py:47)
2023-12-18 21:12:13,416 - app - DEBUG - Dependency(module='mediapipe', package=None, name=None) (ui_registration.py:49)
2023-12-18 21:12:13,417 - app - WARNING - REGISTRATION FAILED: MODULE NOT FOUND (ui_registration.py:57)
Add-on not loaded: 'rigify_animbox' cause: No module named 'rigify_animbox'
Reloading external rigs...
Reloading external metarigs...
Add-on not loaded: 'khaosinstall2_82mantaflowbeta' cause:
Add-on not loaded: 'mixamo_rig' cause: No module named 'mixamo_rig'
Add-on not loaded: 'redshift' cause: No module named 'redshift'
blendartrack-main - Initializing...
blendartrack-main - Attempt to reload...
blendartrack-main - Reload successful!
Register BlendArTrack

Add-on not loaded: 'MCprep_addon' cause: No module named 'MCprep_addon'
WARN (bgl): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v400\blender.git\source\blender\python\generic\bgl.cc:2678 BPyInit_bgl: 'bgl' imported without an OpenGL backend. Please update your add-ons to use the 'gpu' module.
cmolcore imported with success! v1.12
blenderkit addon: Verbose is enabled
blenderkit addon: Read in JSON settings from file
Read blend: "F:\Projects\2023_Recap\scripts\untitled.blend"
2023-12-18 21:12:14,381 - app - INFO - UNREGISTER BLENDARMOCAP (ui_registration.py:70)
2023-12-18 21:12:14,382 - app - DEBUG - <class '_blender.interface.ui_preferences.PREFERENCES_OT_install_dependencies_button'> (ui_registration.py:72)
2023-12-18 21:12:14,382 - app - DEBUG - <class '_blender.interface.ui_preferences.BLENDARMOCAP_preferences'> (ui_registration.py:72)
2023-12-18 21:12:14,382 - app - DEBUG - <class '_blender.interface.ui_panels.UI_PT_warning_panel'> (ui_registration.py:72)
Unregister BlendArTrack
blenderkit INFO: Unregistering BlenderKit add-on [21:12:14.385, __init__.py:2399]
blenderkit ERROR: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=62485): Max retries exceeded with url: /report_blender_quit (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000002008A0E1BD0>, 'Connection to 127.0.0.1 timed out. (connect timeout=0.1)')) [21:12:14.501, __init__.py:2421]

Blender quit
```

The Command i'm trying to use in the script is:

```
"F:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.0\blender.exe" -b "D:\Blender Zeugs\fireplace_01\fireplace_01.blend" -o "F:\Projects\2023_Recap\renders\fireplace_01\01\frame_#####" -F OPEN_EXR -s 1 -e 250
```

I don't see anything else wrong here Thank You for your help in advance

Comment: If you still have problems, please post the command.

Answer (score 0):

It quits because it does not have anything else to do.

Make sure you follow all the instructions for `Command Line Rendering`: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/render.html

To disable all non-default addons just for a session you can use `--factory-startup` this will solve the side addon erroring.

###### The error

In case you need the addon for rendering.

Some addons are required to be turned on for rendering if the `.blend` was created using them, like `rigify`, as they may rely on custom scripts.

The error is a missing site package: https://pypi.org/project/mediapipe/.

The addon version is outdated and the file `ui_registration.py` has been deleted.
https://github.com/cgtinker/BlendArMocap/blob/52c6ea0022827ad58baa48a66ba550903155abf0/_blender/interface/ui_registration.py#L57

You can try to fix it by locating where the package is and adding the next code at the beginning of the `register()` function inside [`__init__.py`](https://github.com/cgtinker/BlendArMocap/blob/main/__init__.py) in the root directory of the addon.

```py
import sys
import os
PATH_TO_MEDIAPIPE = r'C:\somewhere\whatever\site-packages\mediapipe'
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(PATH_TO_MEDIAPIPE))
```

Comment: I tried disabling addons that were causing this error blender still quits but the messages are obviusly gone

Comment: @SDRS Update the question post with the command you are trying to use.

Comment: added the command in the question

Comment: What is the output if you add `--factory-startup` right after the `blender.exe` path?

Comment: Blender 4.0.2 (hash 9be62e85b727 built 2023-12-05 13:01:12)
Read blend: "D:\Blender Zeugs\fireplace_01\fireplace_01.blend"

Blender quit

Comment: Add `-a` at the end.

Comment: Oh my God that helps thank you soooo much